# Why can't I call my WriteLogDataToDb method?

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, rabbitmq

I'm making a user inactivity logger for an internal application at work, and I'm having trouble writing consumed messages to a MySQL database, when I try to call my method that writes the messages to the database, it throws an error:   'AccessEye.LogData' is a 'type', which is not valid in the given context

Any and all help with this would be appreciated, it's a windows forms project with a topshelf service being used as the RabbitMQ Consumer, which will eventually forward messages to the database as mentioned =]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;
using NLog;
using IWshRuntimeLibrary;
using Topshelf;
using System.Data.Odbc;
using EasyNetQ;
using RabbitMQ;
using EasyNetQ.Topology;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using AccessEye;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace LogService
{
    public class WindowsServiceHost : ServiceControl, ServiceShutdown
    {
        public static readonly Logger Logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

        public static void WriteLogDataToDb(LogData data)
        {
            using (var db = new LogService.UserActivityDataContext())
            {
                DbLogData logData = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<LogData, DbLogData>(data);

                int t = (int)data.EventType;

                EventType eventType = db.EventTypes.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Id == t);

                if (eventType == null)
                {
                    eventType = db.EventTypes.Add(new EventType
                    {
                        Event = GetEnumDescriptionAttributeValue(data.EventType),
                        Id = (int)data.EventType
                    });
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }

                logData.EventTypeId = eventType.Id;
                db.LogEvents.Add(logData);

                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        public static string GetEnumDescriptionAttributeValue(Enum value)
        {
            var fieldInfo = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());
            var attributes = (DescriptionAttribute[])fieldInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);
            return attributes.Length > 0 ? attributes[0].Description : value.ToString();
        }

        public bool Start(HostControl hostControl)
        {
            Program.bus = RabbitHutch.CreateBus("host=as01.access.local;virtualHost=DEV-Reece;username=reece;password=reece").Advanced;

            //var bus = RabbitHutch.CreateBus("host=as01.access.local;virtualHost=DEV-Reece;username=reece;password=reece").Advanced;
            var queue = Queue.Declare(true, false, true, null);
            var exchange = Exchange.DeclareFanout("UserActivityFanout", true, false, null);
            var exchangeTopic = Exchange.DeclareTopic("UserActivity", true, false, null);
            queue.BindTo(exchange, "#");
            exchange.BindTo(exchangeTopic, "#");
            Program.bus.Subscribe<AccessEye.LogData>(queue, (msg, messageRecInfo) => Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                WriteLogDataToDb(AccessEye.LogData);

                //AppForm.WriteLogDataToDb(data);
                //Console.WriteLine(msg.Body.UserName + " -- " + msg.Body.ComputerName + " -- " + msg.Body.EventType + " -- " + msg.Body.TeamviewerId);
            }));

            return true;    
        }

        public bool Stop(HostControl hostControl)
        {
            Logger.Trace("STOP");
            Program.bus.Dispose();
            return true;
        }

        public void Shutdown(HostControl hostControl)
        {
            Logger.Trace("SHUTDOWN");
            Program.bus.Dispose();

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing a `Type` as parameter to `WriteLogDataToDb()` method, when it expected an instance of `AccessEye.LogData`.

I don't know where you like to initialize your variable, but to "fix" (you are initializing a default instance with my suggested code) your issue probably you must change this piece of code.

```
Program.bus.Subscribe<AccessEye.LogData>(queue, 
       (msg, messageRecInfo) => Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
       {
            WriteLogDataToDb(new AccessEye.LogData());
       }));
```

Note that I don't know what constructors are defined for `AccessEye.LogData` type, but you probably know.

At the other hand, I suppose that one of the parameters for the lambda expression is an instance of the required type.

What of the `Suscribe()` method is of type `AccessEye.LogData`?

**Edit**:

As OP says in his comment, the solution was to replace the original code with this code snippet:

```
Program.bus.Subscribe<AccessEye.LogData>(queue, 
   (msg, messageRecInfo) => Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
   {
       var data2 = LogDataFactory.CollectData();
       data2.EventType = AccessEye.UserStateEvents.Logon;
       WriteLogDataToDb(data2);
   }));
```

Comment: Nevermind, I resolved this issue in a different way, thanks anyway your answer helped =]

Comment: While accepting my answer is positive for me (thanks!), if the solution you've taken is different, I think it is best you make an answer to your own question with the best/taken solution for your problem. Doing this, you may help anybody that checks this question in the future.

Comment: The solution is quite specific to my situation, I had to write `var data2 = LogDataFactory.CollectData();
                data2.EventType = AccessEye.UserStateEvents.Logon;
                WriteLogDataToDb(data2);`

Answer (score 0):

It would seem your action is incorrect, what you want to write to the database is the *body* of the message, not the *type* of the message;

```
Program.bus.Subscribe<AccessEye.LogData>(queue, (msg, messageRecInfo) => 
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            WriteLogDataToDb(msg.Body);
        }));
```